# Fitting a probability distribution to non i.i.d. data?

Tags: time-series, density-function, extreme-value, iid

I have temperature time series data that I have determined is not independently and identically distributed (from looking at the autocorrelation plots and Ljung-Box tests).

However, I am still able to fit PDFs, typically GEV, gamma, and Weibull distributions to my different data sets, with a $\chi^2$ goodness-of-fit test accepting the null hypothesis. 
So my question is: since these underlying PDFs assume the data is supposed to be i.i.d., and my data is not i.i.d., how should I proceed? How worried should I be about my estimates being biased?

Comment: which estimates?

Comment: Without knowing what the next step(s) you are planning, this question cannot be answered satisfactorily.

Comment: I don't really have a concrete plan from here...

Comment: How do you intend on interpreting these fitted distributions? I have to wonder, because many temperature time series exhibit fluctuations from assignable causes such as diurnal fluctuations, seasons, and so on, whence their distribution reflects a combination of those effects--and might not provide adequate information about anything of interest in the time series. So until you can provide the information @Glen_b is requesting, or *some* indication of what you are trying to accomplish, this question really cannot be objectively answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in extreme values you might use the block maxima approach if your data set is long enough. Use the annual maxima from each year. That is much more likely to be i.i.d. and much more representative of the tail distribution you are interested in. You can also try "Peak over Threshold" approach to use more than the just annual maximums.

Comment: Very good suggestion! Thank you. Some of my data sets are long (i.e. many years), while others aren't. I'll study up on Peak over thresholds.